# Calculate calories burned in app

Tags: swift

I have a tracking app that tracks a users path. The path gets the distance (meters converted to miles or KM depending on the users preference), time (hh:mm:ss), average pace (min/KM or min/mile). When a user firsts signs up they don't need to enter their weight.

I am struggling to find information on how to calculate calories burned for an average walk. I have found this formula to get :

```
Cal burned = (BMR / 24) * MET * T
```

To get BMR I need the users weight, height and age which I may not have initally. Also time is in hours but my time is hh:mm:ss. Should I convert this time to decimal hours?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question, it's a ... biology /nutrition / metabolism question.

Comment: the time, you could convert to seconds, or minutes. for the BMR, you need the weight, height and age or else it wont work

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - It is a programming question with a nutrition component. I am trying to calculate something in side a mobile app. How is that not a programming question?

Comment: @Ricardo Alves - Thanks.

Comment: It's like saying *"I have a spreadsheet question - I am building a spreadsheet of famous people's phone numbers, but I don't know what the President's phone number is, do you?"*. It's a question, but it's not a spreadsheet question. You don't know how to calculate calories burned because you don't have enough information - yes that's a problem, but ... how is it a programming problem, and how is it Swift related?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - OK

Answer (score 0):

Have you asked question regarding formula in fitness forums or similar? I am sure, you will get formulas and examples there.

Regarding the only programming question I might see to help you out with, is here's how to get time in HH:mm:ss

```
// get time in HH:mm:ss format
let date = NSDate()
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
let str = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
print(str)
```

If your formula has "/ 24" in it (is it divided by 24 hours?), then you need a decimal float for hours, like if it's 2:30:00, you need 2,5 hrs.
2 steps here:
1) Divide the minutes of the time into 60
2) Add the decimal number obtained to full hours
(30/60 = 0,5) + 2 = 2,5